# Crop a polygon shape from an image without libraries except numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I have a list of points let's say 5 points. I want to crop the area that this polygon is covering from the image. Here, red areas are the points and I want to crop inside of the white area from the black background.

[image: example]

I am able to do this with cv2.fillConvexPoly() function but I will run this code on GPU so I can not use cv2. I want to do this with only numpy arrays. I have the X and Y coordinates of the points and their orders to draw edges. I could not implement the code without using libraries like PIL or opencv so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at the code of `cv2.fillConvexPoly()` and see how its implemented. You can copy the implementation.

Comment: @EdgarH thank you for your answer. I could not find the python source code of the function. do you know where can I find it? I searched it in their github and in my library but I could not see it.

Comment: there is no python source code. it's C++, compiled, and python calls those functions. in any case, the source of OpenCV is not generally useful to newbies. it's highly optimized.

Comment: you **should** ask how to achieve that on a GPU, and you should present the libraries you use (CUDA? OpenCL?)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am using PyCuda or I will use Numba for it but first, I need to be able to implement this with numpy.

Comment: "crop" might not mean what you intend. sounds like you simply want to **draw** the  thing. cropping is is the term to describe taking a rectangular subregion of an image. you really should [edit] your question and make very clear what the goal is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you could achieve a more optimized approach than `cv2` by using only python. But if you're wondering what would a python + NumPy implementation of `cv2.fillConvexPoly()` look like, this is how I would do it:

1. For each pixel in an image, check if it is inside the polygon
2. If it is not inside, change the alpha value for that pixel to `0` (assuming the image has an alpha channel. Or you could just make that pixel black)

In order to know if a pixel is inside a polygon, you could use the [Winding Number Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) / [Nonzero-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) which states:

> *For any point inside the polygon the winding number would be non-zero.
> Therefore it is also known as the nonzero-rule algorithm.*

And:

> *For a given curve C and a given point P: construct a ray (a straight
> line) heading out from P in any direction towards infinity. Find all
> the intersections of C with this ray. Score up the winding number as
> follows: for every clockwise intersection (the curve passing through
> the ray from left to right, as viewed from P) subtract 1; for every
> counter-clockwise intersection (curve passing from right to left, as
> viewed from P) add 1. If the total winding number is zero, P is
> outside C; otherwise, it is inside.*

[image: ray contruction]

In my approach I won't be adding or subtracting `1`, instead I'll think of it as the number of revolutions, meaning that **if the `sum` of all the angles between the rays is `360`, that means the point is inside the polygon**

```
import numpy as np

def _angle_between_three_points(A, B, C):
    a, b, c = np.array(A), np.array(B), np.array(C)
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b

    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)  # in radians
    
    return np.degrees(angle)  # in degrees

def _get_edges_from_points(points):
    edges = []
    dist = lambda p1, p2: np.hypot(p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1])
    _p = points.copy()
    for i, p in enumerate(points):
        _p.pop(0)
        try:
            next_point = sorted(map(lambda pn: (pn, dist(p, pn)), _p), key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0]
        except IndexError:
            next_point = points[0]
        edges.append((p, next_point))
    return edges

def is_point_inside(point, polygon):
    point = [point[0], point[1]]
    angles = map(lambda edge: _angle_between_three_points(edge[0], point, edge[1]), _get_edges_from_points(polygon))
    return sum(angles) == 360
```

Now you can just apply the `is_point_inside()` to every pixel.

NOTE: It is worth checking out [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/is-the-point-inside-the-polygon-574b86472119) article from Medium's Towards Data Science